# wp_insert_post not working from within wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress problem I am trying to figure out; trying to create a wp-admin script that creates a new wp post…

Here is the code:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'My post Gman99',
    'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status'   => 'draft',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
echo $post_id;
```

And let me stress that this code works fine if I run it on a "front end" page; i just put the code in short code using "short code exec php" plugin and it creates the post no problem and spits out the post id; but when I try to do the same from within wp-admin it fails?  dos anyone have any idea why this would be occurring?

here is the code of the php file that runs in wp-admin:

```
<?php
require_once('./admin.php');
if ( !current_user_can('edit_posts') )
wp_die(__('Cheatin&#8217; uh?'));
require_once('./admin-header.php');
?>
<div class="wrap">
<br/>
<?php
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => 'My post Gman99',
'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
'post_status'   => 'draft',
'post_author'   => 1,
'post_category' => array(8,39)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
echo $post_id;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<h2>You have completed entering your New Slide.</h2>";
echo "<br/>";
?>
</div>
<?php
include('./admin-footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: How and where did you used shortcode in wp-admin area?

Comment: um - I did not use a short code when trying to do it from wp-admin; i used the shorcode when running it on a "front end" page; when i tried to do it from within wp-admin i had the code run from within a php file...

Comment: And whats the PHP file and how did you execute it? Show that code as well.

Comment: ok - here is the code of the php file that runs within wp-admin:

Comment: code is too long; working on shortening it

Comment: i just edited it and it is now there….

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, my own mistake; but thanks so much to Rahil being willing to help…

basically the problem was that I was not calling the file that I thought; and so basically my code to insert the post was not being run when i thought it was; a really rookie mistake...